# how to fetch data from the two table with different foreign key names

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am new to cake php . Please be cool with me . I am trying to fetch the data from the two table `ce_actionitems` and `ce_projects`.
i want to fetch the data from action items . my model is

```
public $hasOne = array(
        'Project' => array(
            'className' => 'Project',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'joinTable' => 'actionitems',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'associatedKey' => 'project_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

but is is returning the null data because it is matching id in projects with id in action items. this is the generated query

> LEFT JOIN `EB`.`ce_projects` AS `Project` ON (`Project`.`id` =
>   `Actionitems`.`id`)

but i want this to be

> LEFT JOIN `EB`.`ce_projects` AS `Project` ON (`Project`.`id` =
>   `Actionitems`.`project_id`)

i got this working if i mention `public $primaryKey = 'project_id';` in my  `Actionitems` but then it stop inserting the action items.

any help will be appriciated.

Comment: From the looks of it you should just be able to have `public $hasOne = ['Project'];`. You only need to configure the association if you are breaking from convention which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

mention 'project_id' as foreign key in Actionitems